# Images rendered too slowly in Chrome in a slideshow gallery

Tags: javascript, css

I have a modal with a slideshow gallery with images whose width is 1920px. Every image is about 600kb. To hide / show slides I use opacity (0 for hidden images, 1 for the currently displayed image). There are 29 images.

I initially used transform: transale() but it was slow too (in Firefox and Chrome). Now, thanks to manipulating opacity it works fast in Firefox but still not in Chrome.

Sliding the images is slow only the first time, after an image appears in the viewport changing it again is fast. All the images are cached.

I don't understand what happens with the images after showing them in the viewport for the first time. What does stay in the browser and make showing and hiding them again much quicker and smoother? Same was happening in Firefox before I used opacity.

I'm just adding and removing classes to show / hide slides after clicking on left or right arrow.

All images are fetched via database which stores only a path to each image.

Chrome developer tools show very long 'Rasterize Paint', sometimes over 2s.

JS

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function goToSlide (n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showCurrentSlide (n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  const slide = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slide-container"));
  slide.forEach(function(item, index) {
    slide[index].classList.remove("slide-anim");
    slide[index].classList.add("slide-hidden");
  });
  if (n > slide.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slide.length;
  }
  slide[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("slide-anim");
  slide[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("slide-hidden");
}
```

CSS

```
.slide-container {
  display: flex;
}

.slide-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide-anim {
  -webkit-animation: next-slide 0.6s ease-out;
          animation: next-slide 0.6s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes next-slide {
  from {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Below class refers to all images which are contained in '.slide-container'*/
.img-slide {
  -ms-grid-row-align: start;
      align-self: start;
  margin: 6.647% 2.068% 0 auto; 
  width: 25%;
}
```

I'm using `display: flex` as every slide contains an image and a description next to it (please see the screenshot).
[image: Galery screenshot]

Comment: Why not change your image sizes to be the exact size you are really using? If you don't want to do that then give your images a height in CSS and their width should scale. If you are assigning `.src` to an existing Image, the new  `.src` may not be in the cache yet. Use separate images so they are loaded into the cache to prevent that.